# Using DataTables on an EmberJS template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, datatable, document-ready

I'm trying to use [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) in my EmberJS application.

In a regular jQuery project, I would always use the document ready event and fire off the `.datatables();` invocation in there.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.has-datatable').dataTable();
});
```

Obviously such an approach doesn't work in an Ember application.

---

After some internet searching, I found this solution that appears to work at first glance:

```
MyEmberApp = Ember.Application.create();

// This would basically run `dataTable();` after
// every view/template rendering.
Ember.View.reopen({
  didInsertElement : function(){
    this._super();
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.afterRenderEvent);
  },
  afterRenderEvent : function(){
    $('.has-datatable').dataTable();
  }
});
```

This works, the datatables plugin is run against my table defined in my `.hbs` template, but some of the rows/cells are empty, and in the console I see:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.

If I disable this *fix* and run the template, I see the plain old table filled in properly with all the data I need.

How can I accomplish what I'm aiming for? I just need to run `$('.has-datatable').dataTable();` guaranteed on a view rendering (or a document-ready-like trigger).

Comment: I don't think it's causing your issue, but you should probably use `this.$` instead of the global jquery reference `$`.

Comment: Why? (By the way, I'm having the same result).

Comment: It's just better practice since it limits the scope of your selector to the view's element instead of the entire page. You could try using the `on` method as it's used in this example:
http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/focusing_a_textfield_after_its_been_inserted/

Comment: Ah, that makes tons of sense! :) Also, I'll try to read your link and see what I can pull out from there.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably wrap it in a [`Component`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html). This example isn't for `DataTables` as I don't have that in use but I use this approach with both `jScrollPane` and `jQuery UI Accordion` (and have also used it for the Bootstrap accordion). The basic approach is this:

**app/components/jqueryui-accordion.js**
(you may have to use different locations and/or slightly different syntax if you're not using `ember-cli`, see the cookbook page linked below).

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend( {
  classNames: 'has-datatable',

  _enableAccordion: function () {
    this.$().accordion({
      animate: 200,
      heightStyle: 'fill',
      icons: false,
    });
  }.on( 'didInsertElement' ),

  _removeAccordion: function () {
    this.$().accordion('destroy');
  }.on( 'willDestroyElement' )
});
```

**app/templates/components/jqueryui-accordion.hbs**

```
{{yield}}
```

To use it in your page, e.g. **app/templates/example.hbs**

```
{{#jqueryui-accordion}}
<span>Content the component displays or works with goes here, inserted where the {{yield}} is</span>
{{/jqueryui-accordion}}
```

The same basic principle is being used at http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/helpers_and_components/ (those examples are without `ember-cli`).

The `afterRender` event you're using is new to me, but might be needed as well and can of course be combined with my example (I didn't want to break it with new code).

You are applying your solution to **every** view however, which might be part of the problem you're having: a parent view would also trigger on the selector if there's a nested `class="has-datatable"` in there.

Answer (score 1):

I have Combined jqgrid and ember

Try the following:

myCallback() - js function

```
App.MyTable = Ember.View.extend({
     didInsertElement : function() {
            this._super();
            Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.didRenderElement);
        },
        didRenderElement : function() {
            this.$().html('<div id="gridWrapper"><table id="list2"></table><div id="gridPager" ></div></div>'
                );
            myCallback(); //inside add your code $('.has-datatable').dataTable();
        }
});
```

add to your index.html {{view App.MyTable}}:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="whatever">

{{view App.MyTable}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded integrating Datatables v2.1.1 into an Ember 2.11 application. 
The first thing you need to do is to change the tag of the component from the default 'div' to 'table' like this.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'table',
  ... <snip> ...
});
```

Create the datatable in the lifecycle hook.

```
didInsertElement () {
   this._super(...arguments);
   this._createDatatables();
}

_createDatatables() {
   // 1. Create column definitions.
   let columns = ... <snip> ...
   // 2. Create the table.
   let table = this.get('_table');
   if(table) {
      table.destroy();
   }
   // Create a new DataTable and remember it.
   table = this.$().DataTable({
     paging: false,
     scrollY: 600,
     scrollX: true,
     columns : columns
    });
    this.set('_table', table);
}
```

Fill the table with data in this way:

```
 _fillDataTables() {
    let table = this.get('_table');
    let dataArray = this.get('data');
    if(!Ember.isNone(table)) {
      table.rows().remove();
      if(!Ember.isNone(dataArray)) {
        table.rows.add(dataArray);
      }
      table.draw();
    }
  }
```

And finally if you  add callbacks or other listeners to the table you better clean this up in the willDestroyElement()  hook.

To recap, what I think went wrong in your code is:

- The tagname of the component has to be 'table'.
- Get a Jquery handle to the component using this.$()
- You can get an application wide handle with Ember.$
- The constructor is DataTable and not dataTable (capital D), but this might have been otherwise in previous versions.